# Add profile avatar to the leaderboard

Tags: php, mysql

I recently made a leaderboard and I would like to make some changes.

[image: That's what the leader board looks like]

This is the code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Likes</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
    $sql = ("SELECT username, likes FROM users ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 5");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $rank = 1;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>
                      <td>{$rank}</td>
                      <td>{$row['username']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['likes']}</td>
                  </tr>";
            $rank++;
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```

Now, what I would like to do is add instead of 'username' the avatar of each user with 'alt' for username. E.g :

```
<img src="<?php echo $example->avater;?>" alt="<?php echo $example->username;?>" />
```

This is the location of avatar in mysql !
[image]
I also have a css code created for the avatar to appear in a round circle.That means we will use

```
<div class="pro_usrs_container">
```

I tried but I don't understand how to make the codes so that I can integrate them in `<td>` instead of `<td> $ row ['username'] </td>`

Thank you very much !

Comment: where is your image location ?

Comment: I will take the photo from the database. The link to the photo is in the "avater" column of the user database.

Comment: What is the value you are getting in `$row['avater']` and what is the path in the server where your images are stored ?

Comment: So select `avater` in your query as well and use that

Comment: I have edited my post. I uploaded a photo with the avatar location in mysql

Comment: I tried but I don't understand how to make the codes so that I can integrate them in <td> instead of <td> $ row ['username'] </td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `avater` in your Query and use it in your table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Likes</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
        $sql = ("SELECT username, avater, likes FROM users ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 5");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $rank = 1;

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) :
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
                <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $rank; ?></td>
                      <td><img src="<?php echo $row['avater'];?>" alt="<?php echo $row['avater'];?>" /></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['likes']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $rank++;
            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly. But the image is seen at its original size. Very big. How do I add a div or css code to see in a small circle?

Comment: You may use your `class` attribute in your `img` tag. Like `<img class="yourClass" src="...">`. Or you may use `height` and `width` attributes in your `img` tag, like `<img height="250px" width="250px"  src="...">`

Answer (score -2):

Based on the requirement above:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Likes</td>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
        $sql = ("SELECT avater, username, likes FROM users ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 5");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $rank = 1;

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr>
                    <td>{$rank}</td>
                    <td><img src="{$row['avater']}" alt="{$row['username']}" /></td>
                    <td>{$row['likes']}</td>
                </tr>";
                $rank++;
            }
       }
   ?>
```

Comment: You're using `<?php echo` inside an `echo`?

Comment: Np. Now you should escape the quotes `"` inside the quotes `"`